# PortfolioAnalytics backtest with defined set of weights

Tags: r

I like the package PortfolioAnalytics a lot and went trough some examples from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/index.html

Now, instead of optimize a portfolio, could I use the package also to calculate certain risk indicators with a set of historical weights? For example the code below gives nice weights and risk contribution over time. Let's assume I have a fixed set of time series data with weights for the assets in a cvs file (below I use random data). What should I do so that I can extract the weights / risk contribution over time in similar graphs?

For example:

```
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
data(edhec)

    R <- edhec[, 1:4]
funds <- colnames(R)

    init.portf <- portfolio.spec(funds, weight_seq=generatesequence(min=0,  max=1, by=0.002))
init.portf <- add.constraint(init.portf, "weight_sum")#, min_sum=0.99, max_sum=1.01)
init.portf <- add.constraint(init.portf, "box", min=0, max=0.65)


init.portf <- add.objective(init.portf, type="return", name="mean", multiplier=0)

# Add objective to minimize portfolio standard deviation
SDRB.portf <- add.objective(init.portf, type="risk", name="StdDev")

# Add StdDev risk budget objective for maximum percentage risk 
SDRB.portf <- add.objective(SDRB.portf, type="risk_budget", name="StdDev", max_prisk=0.4)

# Generate random portfolios
rp <- random_portfolios(init.portf, 5000)

# Run out of sample backtest with yearly rebalancing
SDRB.opt.bt <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(R, SDRB.portf,
                                              optimize_method="random", 
                                              rp=rp,
                                              trace=TRUE, 
                                              rebalance_on="years", 
                                              training_period=100, 
                                              trailing_periods=60)

# print method for optimize.portfolio.rebalancing objects
SDRB.opt.bt

# summary method for optimize.portfolio.rebalancing objects
tmp_summary <- summary(SDRB.opt.bt)
names(tmp_summary)

# print method for summary.optimize.portfolio.rebalancing objects
tmp_summary

# Extractor functions for summary.optimize.portfolio.rebalancing objects
extractWeights(tmp_summary)
extractObjectiveMeasures(tmp_summary)

# Extractor functions for optimize.portfolio.rebalancing objects
tmp_stats <- extractStats(SDRB.opt.bt)
head(tmp_stats[[1]])
tmp_weights <- extractWeights(SDRB.opt.bt)
tmp_obj <- extractObjectiveMeasures(SDRB.opt.bt)

# chart functions for optimize.portfolio.rebalancing
chart.Weights(SDRB.opt.bt)
chart.RiskBudget(SDRB.opt.bt, match.col="StdDev", risk.type="percent")
```

and

random weights for the 6 assets (sorry don't know to set up random weights which tally to 1)

```
##make some random weights
Wa <-edhec[, 1:1]
w1<-runif(152,0,1)
w2<-runif(152,0,1)
w3<-runif(152,0,1)
w4<-runif(152,0,1)
w5<-runif(152,0,1)
w6<-runif(152,0,1)
weightsTest <- merge(Wa,w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6)
weightsTest <- weightsTest[, -(1), drop=FALSE]
##
```

So how can I use weightsTest as historical weights and calculate the risk contribution like chart.RiskBudget does in the first piece of example?

Thanks!

Comment: doesn't answer your specific question, but the following two calls will get you weights that sum to 1 each period ..... 
sums<-apply(weightsTest,1,sum);
tallyTo1<-sweep(weightsTest, 1,sums,'/')

Comment: Hi, thanks that worked! One step further.